# Access textbox with multiple values to query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database, where I have a form with a textbox (named c1) and a button. When I click the button it opens a datasheet form with information filtered by the textbox value.

The button vba looks like this:

```
c1.Value = Replace(c1.Value, ",", " Or ")
DoCmd.OpenForm ("dsForm")
```

The query behind the datasheet looks something like this in design view:

```
Field:      Name1  |  Name2
Criteria:          |  Like [Forms]![Menu]![c1].[value]
```

*This is so I could later export the results of this query to excel.*

So my issue is that I want to enter values into the textbox and separate them with a comma, which would be later turner into an Or by vba. Why I'm doing this with 1 textbox not multiple, is because I could have many values that I want to search by.

Right now it works if I enter one value into the textbox, but when I enter 2 values it's not working. I'm pretty sure that the query is taking the whole statement as a string for example if I enter 110,220 it's supposed to be Like "110" or "220", but on the query it would be Like "110 or 220".

I've tried by setting the field to be either a string or a number as well. How would I manipulate the criteria on a query from vba?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing a SQL string with the IN statement instead of the OR, and using the OpenArgs event to pass data from the main form over to the datasheet form.

Main Form Button Code

```
Dim sql as String

sql = "Select * From [table name] Where Name2 IN (" & c1 & ")"
DoCmd.OpenForm "dsForm", acFormDS, , , , , sql
```

Datasheet form (dsForm) Code -- Use the Form_Load event.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Me.RecordSource = Me.OpenArgs
End Sub
```

The IN statement allows you to use commas. The OpenArgs event allows you to pass values from one form over to another.

Comment: Why couldn't you just use `sql = "WHERE Name2 in (" & c1 & ")"` and then `DoCmd.openform "dsform", acformDS, , sql` and put the SQL statement where the Where statement should be.  Then you don't need to pass any openargs or use the recordsource statement in the other form

Comment: @geeFlo You are correct, that fits the situation even better. Though the proper wording is done without the "WHERE" reserved word.  'sql = Name2 in (" & c1 & ")" '

Answer (score 0):

Actually my first method was terrible, read the values into an array like this:

```
Sub y()
a = "a,b,c,d"

'Split into 1d Array
b = Split(a, ",", , vbTextCompare)

For c = 0 To UBound(b)
    Debug.Print b(c)
Next c

End Sub
```

You can loop through the array as in the debug.print loop and use each value separately.